# I am trying to use hook in functional component while it throws unexpected token parsing error. What is wrong?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use react hooks in functional component but it seems it doesn't work. In the bellow, you will see where the ref is getting used...

```
    import React, { useRef } from "react";
    import { useDetectOutsideClick } from "./useDetectOutsideClick";
    
    import './Header.scss';
    
    const Header = ({ handleChange, type, ...otherProps }) => (
    
     const dropdownRef = useRef(null);
     const [isActive, setIsActive] = useDetectOutsideClick(dropdownRef, false);
     const onClick = () => setIsActive(!isActive);
    
      <nav className="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
        <div className="navbar-brand">
          <a className="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
            <img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" width="112" height="28"/>
          </a>
    ...
          <div onClick={onClick}  ref={dropdownRef}
          className={`navbar-item has-dropdown ${isActive ? "active" : "inactive"}`} >
          <a className="navbar-link">
            More
          </a>

          <div className="navbar-dropdown">
            <a className="navbar-item">
              About
            </a>
            <a className="navbar-item">
              Jobs
            </a>
            <a className="navbar-item">
              Contact
            </a>

            <a className="navbar-item">
              Report an issue
            </a>


  </div>
  </div>
    ...
```

It throws parsing error in the following lines:

```
     const dropdownRef = useRef(null);
     const [isActive, setIsActive] = useDetectOutsideClick(dropdownRef, false);
     const onClick = () => setIsActive(!isActive);
```

How can be it fixed?

Comment: can you show us a snipit of "useDetectOutsideClick" ?

Comment: also if you wanna implement OutsideClick Detector, you can use a higher order component for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put your active stuff in an object like this:

```js
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { useDetectOutsideClick } from "./useDetectOutsideClick";

import './Header.scss';

const Header = ({ handleChange, type, ...otherProps }) => (

 const dropdownRef = useRef(null);
 const [isActive, setIsActive] = useDetectOutsideClick({
    dropdownRef: "",
    active: false
 });
 const onClick = () => setIsActive({
  dropDownRef: dropdownRef,
  active: !isActive.active
 });

  <nav className="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
    <div className="navbar-brand">
      <a className="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
        <img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" width="112" height="28"/>
      </a>

      <a role="button" className="navbar-burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navbarBasicExample">
        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
...
```

Also make sure you add the ref tag to your element:

```js
<nav>
  <Dropdown ref={dropDownRef}>
    //stuff
  </Dropdown>
</nav>
```

Comment: @Dave can i see what element your putting the ref on? The element your putting it on might not be ref suitable?

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://usehooks.com/useOnClickOutside/) is a documentation on how to use useOnClickOutside hook and how to write it.

I believe there is a problem in your useDetectClickOutside hook if it's possible to have that code too that would help.